# lit.dev typescript error 'TemplateResult' is not generic

Tags: typescript, lit, lit-html

I am using `lit@3.0.0`

When building my typescript component it adds this as the `my-component.d.ts`:

```
render(): import("lit-html").TemplateResult<1> | undefined;
```

Problem is that this throws an error:

```
 error TS2315: Type 'TemplateResult' is not generic.
```

I am using `typescript@5.2.0`

Can anyone tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: Did you try to update lit?

Comment: works for me: https://tsplay.dev/N9Y0JN maybe lit-html is outdated